# What's the name of the app made by Apple for browsing iOS documentation?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Someone said there was an special iPad app from Apple that is made for browsing the iOS documentation and other related things. What's the name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not a separate app that I know of. Rather, if you visit http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html on an iPad, the website is specially formatted for viewing on an iPad.

Comment: yeah, maybe it was a web app... not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like snark, but the only one I know of is Safari.app. When visiting the documentation site with Mobile Safari, it's served up differently.